# LabelのBackgroundを、ColorDialogのcolorに適用したいです

Tags: c#, wpf

LabelのBackgroundを、System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialogのcolorに適用したいです。
方法が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Label`の背景は単色とは限りませんが、`SolidColorBrush`であれば

```
var scb = label.Background as SolidColorBrush;
if (scb!=null)
{
    var c = scb.Color;
    var gdipColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);
}
```

と`System.Drawing.Color`に変換できると思います。

またWPFとWindows Formsダイアログを相互運用する場合、`WindowInteropHelper`を使用して`IWin32Window`を実装します。

```
class MainWindow : Window, System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        return new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    }
}
```

こうすることで`ShowDialog()`時に`Owner`としてWPFウィンドウが指定できます。

Comment: 上記の方法で解決することが出来ました。
早い返答に助かりました、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

WPFでは、System.Windows.Media名前空間を使用します。

[Color 構造体](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.media.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

System.Drawing名前空間は、Windowsフォーム用であるため、WPFでは、使用しません。